# Calculate Data Iris with Mean of Column

Tags: r, iris-dataset

I have problem in R with Data Iris, Let us know how to calculate iris data - mean of all column (4 column) in iris data with looping

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with your code so far and the desired result. Tell us where exactly you are getting stuck.

Comment: `colMeans(iris[-5])`

Comment: i have colMeans(iris[,4]) but i cant my iris data - mean

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
data("iris")
    iris.numeric <- iris[,c(1:4)]
    colMeans(iris.numeric)
    
    for (i in 1:4) { 
      print(mean(iris[,i]))
      }
    
    normalize <- function(numbers)
                 {    (numbers - mean(numbers))/sd(numbers)
                 }
    new.iris <- apply(iris.numeric, 2, normalize)
    apply(new.iris, 2, mean)
    apply(new.iris, 2, sd)
```

Comment: so how about data in each colomn to minus that mean?

Comment: You mean normalize?

Comment: i mean each data of column - mean of that column so the answer is matrix 150x4

Comment: yeah, so then remove /sd(numbers) in normalize function and it will serve your purpose.